# Parameters of gaussian distribution, which is generated using central limit theorem

Tags: normal-distribution

In a software I am working on (sensor simulation), I needed to generate normally distributed noise for simulated sensor signals. I used the central limit theorem. I generated 20 random numbers and built an average out of them to approximate the gaussian distribution.

So I took the "measured" signal and generated 20 numbers from **`-noiseMax`** to **`+noiseMax`** and averaged them. I added the result to the signal to have noise.

Now, for my university, I have to describe this Gaussian distribution by its **mean** and **variance**. Ok, **mean** will be **0** but I have absolutely no idea how to convert **noiseMax** in my program into the variance. Googling haven't helped much.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the "random numbers" you used come from the uniform distribution. The [variance of the uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Moments_and_parameters) is
$$
\frac1{12} (b - a)^2
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the lower and upper limit, so in your case
$$
\frac13 \mathtt{noiseMax}^2.
$$
The [variance of the sum of independent random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29) is the sum of the variances, so for $n$ random variables it is
$$
\frac n3 \mathtt{noiseMax}^2;
$$
in your case, $n = 20$. But you're interested in the average, which is the sum divided by $n$. For the variance, this makes a factor $\sqrt n$, and the variance of the average is
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}3 \mathtt{noiseMax}^2.
$$

Btw., there are better ways to [generate normally distributed random numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution), and most modern programming languages have an implementation of one of these methods.